# How can I correct error message that appears each time I launch Mathematica?

Tags: warning-messages

Each time I launch *Mathematica* I get the following error message :

**The specified setting for the option Magnification cannot be used.**

I have gone to the option inspector and have confirmed that the setting for Magnification appears to be correctly set.

Thank You for any help.

Comment: Try renaming or deleting this file: `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "FrontEnd", "init.m"}]`

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

From the comment by Stefan.

> Try renaming or deleting this file: `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "FrontEnd", "init.m"}`]